# Attribution of a value with socket.io and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, socket.io

I'm trying to get data with socket.io with this code:

**server.js:**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Un client est connecté !');
    retrieveDB((res) =>{
      socket.emit('dataSend', res);
    });
});
```

**filesearch.component.ts:**

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
options = []
socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4200');

ngOnInit(){
    this.socket.on('dataSend', function(message) { 
            this.options = message; 
            alert(message); 
        });
    if(this.myControl.value !='') { 
      this.init = 1; 
      this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(val => this.filter(val))
        );
    } else {
      this.init = 0;
    } 
  }

 filter(val: string): string[] {
    if(this.init){
      return this.options.filter(option =>
        option.toLowerCase().includes(val.toLowerCase()));
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
```

The `ngOnInit()` should retrieve the data with `socket.on()` and the 2nd part initialise an autocompletion (https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview) but I always have a value of `options` nul. I know that this code is wrong because `socket.on` works asynchronously but I don't find how to correct it.

I tried to change the code by doing this:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.socket.on('dataSend', function(message) { 
            this.options = message; 
            alert(message); 
        });
  }

onClick(){
  if(this.myControl.value !='') { 
      this.init = 1; 
      this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
          startWith(''),
          map(val => this.filter(val))
        );
    } else {
      this.init = 0;
    }
```

With the `onClick()` running when I click on the searchbar. But I still got the same result. So i'm begining to think that the probleme is elsewhere on my code. `alert(this.options)` return the good value but that's all.

I also tried to create a `Display Button` to display the value of `options` when I click on it but I still don't have the right answer.

I also tried to create an asynchrone function with a callback in `ngOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.socket.on('dataSend', function(message) { 
        this.initialise(message, this.autocompletion()); 
    });
  }

initialise(message, callback){
    this.options = message;
    alert(message); 
    callback();
}

autocompletion(){
    if(this.myControl.value !='') { 
      this.init = 1; 
      this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filter(val))
    );
    } else {
      this.init = 0;
}
```

But that's not working.

Thank you for helping me or at least reading this message.

**EDIT:** I tried an other method

I have a **dictionnarymanagerService**:

```
export class DictionnarymanagerService implements OnInit{

  data: any = ['test2'];
  socket = io.connect('http://localhost:4200');

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
     this.socket.on('dataSend', function(message) { 
            this.options = message; 
            alert(message); 
        });
  }
```

And I have in my **fileSearchComponent** only:

options = []

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.options = this.dictionnaryManager.data;
  if(this.myControl.value !='') { 
  this.init = 1; 
  this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(val => this.filter(val))
    );
} else {
  this.init = 0;
 } 
}
```

But because `socket.on` is asynchrone I don't have the right value (`options` takes the value `'test2`. How can I do to send the value of `data` after the end of the `socket.on()`

Comment: can you try adding a 1 or 2 second timeout around the `socket.emit()` bit of code? i suspect the value is emitted before the page has rendered, meaning the data is send before you can read it

Comment: If it was the case I wouldn't be able to display the data with the alert, isnt it ?

Comment: I misread that part, so you can alert this.options but not message?

Comment: when I'm on the `socket.on()` I can see both the message and this.options but I when I'm not in it I still have `this.options=[]` even when I try to display it with a button. I thought it was a problem with the asynchronous function but it seems to be something else. As if the this.options in the `socket.on()` and the `options` were 2 differents objects.

Comment: do you have a class/component in the filesearch.component.ts file? did you strip out the parts that arent needed?

Comment: A class/component ? Yes I don't write all the content of the filesearch.component.ts file

Comment: Your socket emit only when a client connect ? what is the answer exactly send by the server (typeOf) ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't use arrow functions, so `this` refers to the function you provide in `socket.on`.
Arrow functions don't capture `this`.

You can checkout this question for more information:
[Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Following code should work because of the arrow function not capturing `this`, therefore `this` still refers to the instance of your component class:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.socket.on('dataSend', message => this.options = message);
```